# How do I expose children destination (Fragment/Dialog) to the Parent Graph of Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation, android-navigation-graph, android-deep-link

I've multi-modules setup with Navigation Component with multiple navigation graphs which all have been included in the main app's navigation graph file. But when I try to navigate to one of the children within another module navigation graph this error is being thrown.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.app, PID: 26724
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination com.example.app:id/singleTranslationHadithDetailDialog cannot be found from the currentdestination Destination(com.example.app:id/duaDetailListFragment) label=DuaDetailListFragment class=com.example.app.ui.fragments.dua.DuaDetailListFragment
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1216)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1149)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1131)
```

As per official documenentation:
**Nested graphs have their own start destination and don’t expose their child destinations separately.**

I'm trying the DeepLink solution (and some place I already have DeepLink implemented), but the problem is the targeted destination (action/destination com.example.app:id/singleTranslationHadithDetailDialog) I'm trying to go has params with an array of integer, How can add integer[] in DeepLink Uri path parameter like following:

```
<argument
        android:name="references"
        app:argType="integer[]"
        app:nullable="false" />
```

Now, what should I do? How can I overcome this situation?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you [read the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-multi-module#across)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I've updated my question with DeepLink's parameter related issue I'm facing.